# Python selenium webdriver is not seeing all table data from from web page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having an issue retrieving all table data from what appears to be a dynamic table created by java script.

I'm currently using python along with the selenium package with webdriver.  On any static tables I'm able to dig into the driver.get("webpage") and then feed that info to beautifulsoup in order to extract the various tags but with this other webpage I'm not able to see the data inside of my driver.page_source.

Is this because the table is being generated by javascript? 
Do I need to use another command set within the selenium package?

Comment: Also when I look at the inspect page within my chrome driver page I see all of the data that I want and I'm able to create xreferences of them, when I look into the driver.page_source I'm not able to see these tables at all...

Comment: It is possible that the page is not fully loaded and page source did not return all the data. I suggest to use dynamic page waits and possibly use selenium to extract the table rather than bs in this case.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and [mcve]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  As Sureshmani indicates, you should try to wait: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Yep it was indeed a timing issue, I hard coded in some 5s pauses and all is well.  I’ll check around for how to add in some dynamic waits...